# Making button to Posting link to a website on friends's wall 

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Is it possible to do this, There is an asp.net website.
There will be a button to invite friend to that website.
What the invite button do is after clicked. it will ask the user to login to facebook.
After login. The list of friends will be show to let user select that which friends will be invited.
After use have select the friends to be invited and click submit, The link to that website will be posted on their Facebook's wall.

Comment: Try reading http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web. There are a couple of code snippets that can help you get on your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you'll need to have a facebook application and ask for the publish_stream permission.

when you have that you simply get the user friends ([/me/friends](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends)), then you'll need to render the list yourself since the only plugin that facebook offers is the [Request Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) which works just for canvas pages and does not post to the wall.

After the user has selected the users using your widget, you simply post to the selected ids walls ([/USER_ID/feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed)).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the [C# Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk). There is sample code showing how to manage the login process on the sdk's github page.

After the user is logged in, you can get a list of the user's friends with this call to the Facebook API:

```
www.graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends
```

which retrieves a list of friends with their user_ids and names.

If your app is a [Canvas](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) app, you can use the [Request Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to invite the user's friends using the user_ids from the /friends call. This will send an invitation to the friend but won't post to the wall.

If that doesn't meet your needs and you want the user to post directly to a friend's wall, issue a POST to:

```
www.graph.facebook.com/FRIENDS_USER_ID/feed
```

with these params:

```
message
name (sender's name)
caption
link (your url)
description
picture (url to picture)
```

Comment: The requests dialog won't help him with posting to the selected users wall.

Comment: True. I've added how to post to wall to the answer.

Comment: @Nitzan. Sorry, I didn't see that you had posted the /feed details already in your own answer when you commented on my answer. +1 to your answer.@Sarawut - Nitzan's answer is the earliest complete answer.

Comment: :) It's not "first to answer is to be accepted", he should accept the one that helps him more. Thanks though.